# What's the point of .slice(0) here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, type-conversion, slice

I was studying the jQuery source when I found this (v1.5 line 2295):

```
namespace = new RegExp("(^|\\.)" +
  jQuery.map( namespaces.slice(0).sort(), fcleanup ).join("\\.(?:.*\\.)?") + "(\\.|$)");
```

My question is, why use `slice(0)` here?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`sort()` modifies the array it's called on - and it isn't very nice to go around mutating stuff that other code might rely on.

`slice()` always returns a new array - the array returned by `slice(0)` is identical to the input, which basically means it's a cheap way to duplicate an array.

Comment: @ide answer is more precise : "also used to convert array-like objects into arrays"

Answer (score 36):

`arr.slice(0)` makes a copy of the original array by taking a slice from the element at index 0 to the last element.

It was also used to convert array-like objects into arrays. For example, a DOM [`NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) (returned by several DOM methods like [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)) is not an array, but it is an array-like object with a `length` field and is indexable in JavaScript. To convert it to an array, one often used:

```
var anchorArray = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'), 0)
```

Now, ES2015's spread syntax is used to convert iterable objects, including `NodeList` and `HTMLCollection`, to arrays:

```
const anchorArray = [...document.getElementsByTagName('a')]
```

Comment: slice is 'undefined' for the value returned by document.getElementsByName (in Firefox 3.16).  I used:  var iiNodes=[], tmp = editorDocument.getElementsByName("intInfo");
for (var ii=0; ii<tmp.length; ii++) { iiNodes.push(tmp[ii]); }
   to get around the problem.

Comment: HTMLCollection.slice is undefined but Array.slice does exist, hence the [].slice.call business.

Comment: In an example I saw, `const nav = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.nav'), 0);` why is using Array.prototype better than []?

Answer (score 8):

`slice(0)` creates a new array identical to the original array. Many times you want to preserve your original array and create a new one.

If you use `slice(1)`, it will create a different array starting from index position 1.

Similar things hold for strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

`slice(0)` allows you to return an array of the existing array you're referencing, in this case namespaces.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what @Anon said:

The `slice()` method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.

Example1:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
var citrus = fruits.slice(1, 3);
```

The result of citrus will be:

```
Orange,Lemon
```

Example2:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
var citrus = fruits.slice(-3, -1);
```

The result of citrus will be:

```
Lemon,Apple
```

Further information can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp).

Comment: No, the result will be `["Lemon", "Apple"]` to be precise. And we all know what `slice()` does. Stackoverflow isn't for regurgitating documentation. The question is about what the point of `slice(0)` is. Which in this context your question does not answer at all.