# Constant value changes regardless of being constant; also, changes to one row of 2D array propagate to others

Tags: javascript, arrays, constants

I was trying to do the 6th day of AdventOfCode.com, when I stumbled upon an annoying problem, that I don't know the cause of. I

```
var input = ["turn on 7,6 through 9,6","turn on 1,3 through 6,9"];
var grid = 0;

function Create2Darray(dimension) {
    var arr = [0];
    var arr2 = [0];

    for (i=0; i<dimension; i++) {
        arr2[i] = 0;
    }
    for (k=0; k<dimension; k++) {
        arr[k] = arr2;
    }
    return arr;
}

grid = Create2Darray(10);
const p = grid; // THIS IS WHAT IT IS ALL ABOUT

temp = grid[4];
    temp[5] = 3;
grid[4] = temp;

p; // outputs [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]] to console.
// Although we said: const p = grid;
// And at that time, grid was equal to [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Secondly
this:

```
temp = grid[4];
temp[5] = 3;
grid[4] = temp;
```

What I expected was this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

but I got:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

so the core questions:

- Why did CONSTANT p change?
- Why did ALL the "sub-arrays" within the main arrays change while I only selected the 5th value in the 4th "sub-array"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## About reference/copy

Javascript works "by reference", not "by copy" like C++. This means that after:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [a, a];
```

`b` is an array containing two references to the same array `a`, not two copies of `a`. For example after

```
b[0][0] = 99;
```

also `b[1][0]` will be `99` because `b[0]` and `b[1]` are references to the very same object.

If you want to build a matrix you need to build each row separately... for example:

```
var grid = [];
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    grid.push(new Array(100));
}
// Now grid is a matrix of 100x100 undefined elements
```

## About const

Declaring a `const` reference to an array doesn't prevent the array content from being modified, you're only prevented from reassigning `grid` to reference something else.

Comment: So if I want "grid" have a 1000x1000 grid, how would I do that without having the issues where grid[1] and grid[2] change at the same time?

Comment: @AgentM: You need to build it in a loop... see edited answer.

Comment: problem is: I need all the values to be 0 and not undefined.

Comment: @AgentM: the you need to make another loop and set `grid[i][j]=0`

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to create a copy of an array is to use [slice(0)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), for example instead of

```
for (k=0; k<dimension; k++) {
    arr[k] = arr2;
}
```

you could have

```
for (k=0; k<dimension; k++) {
    arr[k] = arr2.slice(0);
}
```

and then the code works as expected: every row of 2D array has the same content but the rows can be modified independently. See also: [What's the point of .slice(0) here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024085/whats-the-point-of-slice0-here)

Comment: Caution: as the MDN docs say, this is only a shallow copy: good for constructing a 2D array of scalar values, but not for 3D arrays. Fortunately, 2D is the most common kind of multiple-dimensional arrays.