# gApps script: deleteRow() does not work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Firstly, here’s the code I try to get to work:

```
function moveChecked(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetSrc = ss.getSheetByName("combo (latest)");
  var sheetTgt = ss.getSheetByName("combo (corrected)")
  var sheetSrcData = sheetSrc.getDataRange().getValues();
  var i, j;
  var valuesC = new Array();
  var rowsC = new Array();
  var rowsCk = 0;

  // Find rows label as [c]reate
  for(i=0; i<sheetSrcData.length; i++){
    if(sheetSrcData[i][84] == "c"){
      for(j=0; j<86; j++){  // 86th is the CH column
        valuesC[j] = sheetSrcData[i][j]
      }
      sheetTgt.appendRow(valuesC);
      rowsC[rowsCk] = i+1;
      rowsCk++;
    }
  }

  // Delete moved rows from `sheetSrc`
  for(i=0; i<rowsCk.length; i++){
    sheetSrc.deleteRow(rowsC[i]);
  }
}
```

Last part of the code, where I try to delete the rows moved/copied to another sheet (`sheetTgt`), does not delete any rows at all, i.e. it does delete the rows. However, the `rowsC` array does contain all the rows I need to delete. The whole code run without error.

Comment: What was the error? What did the Execution Transcript say? Also Try `rowsC.reverse()` to start from the bottom up.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is **not** a sufficient problem description. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @I'-'I, there was no error, it run without error, but did not delete those rows I needed it to delete.

Comment: @tehlowch, I am sorry if is not sufficient according to you or the rules, but in my opinion, if something should _delete_ some rows and it _does not work_, this statement implies that the problem lays in _not deleting those rows_. Don’t you think?

Comment: @tukusejssirs that part is obvious. But what is not obvious is if it works, but in a way that you do not want - such as deleting the "wrong" (to you) rows, deleting no rows, throwing an error, etc. All of those qualify as "it doesn't work." Asking the person with the issue to elaborate and be specific about what is expected and what actually occurs is normal.

Comment: @tehlowch, okay, I, hopefully, have made it more clear. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `rowsCk` is a integer and not a array,thus doesn't have length property.
- When deleting rows, start from the bottom to avoid changing row numbers of rows,that are to be deleted in future.

Try Changing from:

```
// Delete moved rows from `sheetSrc`
for(i=0; i<rowsCk.length; i++){
```

To:

```
// Delete moved rows from `sheetSrc`
rowsC.reverse(); //array reversed
for(i=0; i<rowsC.length; i++){ //k removed
```

Answer (score 2):

[deleteRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition) require an integer as parameter an it refers to the row position starting at 1.

To delete several consecutive rows at once you could use [deleteRows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition-howmany).

To delete several non-consecutive rows make an array of row numbers to be deleted, then use a loop or a array method like forEach to use `deleteRow(rowNumber)` where rowNumber is a variable to handle the row position of the rows to be deleted.

> IMPORTANT NOTE: Loop the array in reverse order in order to avoid to have to adjust the row position of the pending to delete rows.

- [Javascript / angular - Loop through array backwards with forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682962/1595451)
- [Is there a way to use map() on an array in reverse order with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36415904/1595451)

Comment: although I need to delete several rows, they are not consecutive. They might be, for example, rows number 5, 10, 560, 589. Therefore, the `deleteRows` function won’t help me.

Comment: @tukusejssirs please add that to your question to make it clear what are you looking for.

Comment: Anyway, my answer explains why your code doesn't work: It's not using the correct syntax.

Comment: Yeah, now your answer states, basically, the same as the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536357/3408342) answer, therefore it is correct. However, it was anwered sooner and for this reason I keep it as correct answer.

Comment: @tukusejssirs : You can choose the answer that pleased you more, just bear in mind that the meaning of the tick mark is "accepted answer" instead of "correct answer" (if an answer  is incorrect and unhelpful, then downvote it, if its helpful, upvote it) :)

Comment: My mistake: in my previous comment to your answer I wanted to type ‘… I keep it as accepted answer’. I think both are correct and helpful and I am not about to downvote any of it (instead, I’ve already upvoted both of them ;)).